# Microsoft Azure App Config - how to view changes by user?

Tags: azure, configuration

We're using Azure App Config to manage Feature Flags for deploying partially dark software to Azure. However, I haven't been able to find any information how to see WHO made a change to a specific feature flag. The basic logs don't contain this and I'm not sure how to setup the advanced logging that might be required.

I've done a bunch of web searches for this info but haven't found anything other than a list of the http queries to the config. I'm surprised that such a basic piece of change tracking information would be so hard to find.

There is also a compare feature in Azure to show the state of the configuration at two different times. This works, but it does not contain information on who made the change being shown.

Comment: Hi, did you find any way to achieve this ? Change Analysis does not seem to be usable for App Configuration. And there is absolutely no documentation from Microsoft on this topic, the only documented logs are HTTP requests.

Answer (score -1):

I belieave that Azure Application Change Analysis can help you here. It shows old and new values as well as who made the change.

Comment: I have researched a lot and haven't found any way to monitor Azure App Configuration (AAC) changes in Change Analysis. This tools seems to be available only for Azure App Service. So this is of no help for AAC.